# "In the lock" or "into the lock"

Tags: prepositions

Should it be

> She put the key INTO the lock.

or

> She put the key IN the lock.

Which is the correct preposition to use here?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct are perfectly natural to use.

Looking at the definitions from Google:
In: "expressing the situation of something that is or appears to be enclosed or surrounded by something else" - We can see that this fits the situation when the key is inside the lock. Since you are putting it there you are "putting it in"

Into: "expressing movement or action with the result that someone or something becomes enclosed or surrounded by something else." - We are moving the key and as a result it will be inside the lock, so this fits too.

I would guess that in casual spoken English, "put in" is more common simply because it's one less syllable to say so the 'to' gets dropped, but I could be wrong about this or it could be a regional thing(I'm from England).

Comment: "Put X in Y" is also common in USA

Answer (score 1):

With *put*, most prepositions expressing a spatial location are interpreted as a destination:

- Put the key **in** the lock
- Put the flowers **on** the table
- Put the picture **above** the sofa

etc. **Into** and **onto** can also be used with *put* to make the destination part of the meaning even more explicit. There is effectively no difference between *put the key **in** the lock* and *put the key **into** the lock*.